# React material-ui links

Tags: reactjs

I am using react material ui. In my header i have used links as well as tabs both. Please tell me how to do linking using material links as we can't use to. Can it be done by on click method and navigate to that page as well as what changes i need to do in my app.tsx file. please help me. I am beginner. Home I had made a component name home but how can i call on click of link?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { makeStyles, createStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'; 
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Home2 from '../pages/Home2';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      '& > * + *': {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
        color:"#F08713",
        paddingRight: "revert",
        borderRight: "1px solid #ddd"
      },
    },
  }),
);
function Links() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const preventDefault = (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => event.preventDefault();
  
    return (
                <Typography className={classes.root}>
                    <Link 
                        underline ="hover"
                        component="button"
                        href="Home">
                       Home
                    </Link>
                    <Link
                        underline ="hover"
                        component="button"
                        href="#/home2">
                        For home2
                    </Link>
                </Typography>
    );
}

export default Links
```

Comment: Hi @anjali, follow this sample link it will help you to make routing in your sample app..
https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/6517/react-router-tutorial